# Telerik/radgrid Equivalent (Find row items/values)?

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid, datakey

Does anyone know the Telerik/radgrid equivalent of the following statement?

```
e.InputParameters["id"] = 
   Convert.ToString(myRadgrid.DataKeys[myradgrid.SelectedIndex].Value);
```

I'm trying to find the row items/values, and haven't been able to figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
myRadgrid.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues[myradgrid.SelectedIndex]["YourDataKeyName"]
```